# How can I populate a "Months" combobox and a "Years" combobox from a supplied year, and have their values default to the last month?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, date, combobox

I need to let the user select a month and a year. Usually, they will want the last month (e.g., if it's December 18th, 2015, they will normally want to select November 2015). So I want those values to be the ones pre-selected in the comboboxes.

How can I do this (in C#) and also have it be "December 2015" once crossing the Rubicon (Euphrates?) to January 2016?

I also want it to not add 2016 until it *is* 2016 (and so on, as the years go by) and start from a predetermined year (not year 0 or 1970 or anything like that, necessarily).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames(v=vs.110).aspx) to find month names for a culture.
Some cultures have 13 months, so `DateTimeFormat.MonthNames` returns an array with 13 month.

But since it seems you want to use Gregorian calendar, you only need to use 12 month names and I used `InvariantCulture` to get month names.

You can use such code:

```
monthComboBox.DataSource = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat
                                                     .MonthNames.Take(12).ToList();
monthComboBox.SelectedItem = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat
                                        .MonthNames[DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month - 1];

yearComboBox.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1983, DateTime.Now.Year - 1983 + 1).ToList();
yearComboBox.SelectedItem = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

You can use `CurrentCulture` or some other culture you prefer.

Comment: For **current month** change this part of the code: `.MonthNames[DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month]`

Answer (score 1):

This should work (assuming the form on which your comboboxes live is named "mainForm", and the comboboxes are named "comboBoxMonth" and "comboBoxYear"):

```
private void mainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateMonthsAndYears();
}

private void PopulateMonthsAndYears()
{ 
    const int DECEMBER = 11;
    const int BEGIN_YEAR = 1983; // KCMS
    comboBoxMonth.Items.AddRange(PlatypusConstsAndUtils.MonthsFull.ToArray<object>());
    comboBoxMonth.SelectedIndex = PlatypusConstsAndUtils.GetIndexForPreviousMonth();

    comboBoxYear.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(BEGIN_YEAR, DateTime.Now.Year - BEGIN_YEAR + 1).ToList();
    comboBoxYear.SelectedIndex = comboBoxYear.Items.IndexOf(DateTime.Now.Year);

    // However, if it is January (and thus the month is set to December), set the year to previous also
    if (comboBoxMonth.SelectedIndex == DECEMBER)
    {
        comboBoxYear.SelectedIndex = comboBoxYear.Items.IndexOf(DateTime.Now.Year - 1);
    }
}
```

...and the class that holds the month vals (of course, you can change the string vals to Spanish or German or Klingon or whatever "floats your boat"):

```
public static class PlatypusConstsAndUtils
{

    public static List<string> MonthsFull = new List<string>
    {
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
    };

    public static int GetIndexForPreviousMonth()
    {
        // Months are 1-based, but return the index, which is 0-based, so decrement it
        const int JANUARY = 1;
        const int DECEMBER = 12;
        int prevMonth;
        int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
        if (currentMonth == JANUARY)
        {
            prevMonth = DECEMBER - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            prevMonth = DateTime.Now.Month - 2;
        }
        return prevMonth;
    }
    . . .
```

Comment: [CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames(v=vs.110).aspx) has the advantage to be localized.

Comment: Agree with Steve, and also, just use `DateTime.AddMonths(-1)`.  No need for complex logic of your own.